# Data automatically saved offline without using any type of database in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, connectivity

I am trying to create an online app with flutter but the first time when opening app without internet connection , I found that all data that fetched before is still present without using local data base in app ? Why is this happening ? and how to check internet continuously ?

```
    import 'package:baqal/src/bloc/banners/banners.dart' as banners;
import 'package:baqal/src/bloc/main_categories/main_categories.dart'
    as main_categories;
import 'package:baqal/src/notifiers/categories_provider.dart';
import 'package:baqal/src/notifiers/provider_notifier.dart';
import 'package:baqal/src/ui/common/banner_item.dart';
import 'package:baqal/src/ui/common/loading_main_categories.dart';
import 'package:baqal/src/ui/common/main_category_item.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:baqal/src/di/app_injector.dart';
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';

  class CategoriesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoriesScreenState createState() => _CategoriesScreenState();
    }

    class _CategoriesScreenState extends State<CategoriesScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
    final categoriesCubit = getItInstance<main_categories.MainCategoriesCubit>();
    final bannersCubit = getItInstance<banners.BannersCubit>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchMainCategories();
    fetchBanners();
    super.initState();
  }

  fetchMainCategories() async {
    categoriesCubit.fetchMainCategories();
  }

  fetchBanners() async {
    bannersCubit.fetchBanners();
  }
  updateData()async{
    categoriesCubit.fetchMainCategories();
    bannersCubit.fetchBanners();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => updateData(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            bannersDataBuilder(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            mainCategoriesDataBuilder(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget mainCategoriesDataBuilder() {
    return BlocBuilder<main_categories.MainCategoriesCubit,
        main_categories.MainCategoriesState>(
        bloc: categoriesCubit,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, main_categories.MainCategoriesState state) {
          if (state is main_categories.Loading) {
            return loadingMainCategories();
          } else if (state is main_categories.Loaded) {
            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: state.mainCategories.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return MainCategoryItem(
                  mainCategory: state.mainCategories[index],
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (state is main_categories.Error) {
            return Text(state.error);
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }

  Widget bannersDataBuilder() {
    return BlocBuilder(
      bloc: bannersCubit,
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is banners.Loaded) {
          return Container(
            height: 220,
            child: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: state.banners.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                  return (BannerItem(banner: state.banners[i]));
                }),
          );
        } else if (state is banners.Loading) return Shimmer.fromColors(
          baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
          highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
          // enabled: _enabled,
          child: Container(height: 220,color: Colors.white,)
        );

        return Container();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

here is the code of one screen

Comment: Can you show some code snippets?

Comment: @ArturSikora ok ............

Comment: Maybe the `wantKeepAlive` is preserving the state

Comment: @gtxtreme it preserves screen state only in app life cycle , I mean that when closing app and open it again without wifi or mobile data I found that data fetched before is still present  even without using wantKeepAlive , I don't use methods to check internet connection but I am wondering why data was saved without using local data base